# Is there a space where the complement of a positive set is a negative set?

Tags: measure-theory

If $\mu$ is a signed measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$, a measurable space, then $E \in \mathcal{A}$ is positive if $\mu{(F)}\geq0$ (and negative if $\mu{(F)}\leq0$) where $F \in E$ and $F$ is any measurable set in $E$. My question is: could positive sets be the complement of negative sets in some space? And is this space interesting? Or is it just an irrelevant property?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Consider any non-empty set $X$ with two distinct points $x\ne y$ and define
$$\mu =  \delta_x-\delta_y.$$

Then $$\mu(\{x\})= 1, \quad \mu(\{x\}^c)= -1.$$

Answer (score 1):

Also the zero measure ($\mu(E) = 0$ for all measurable $E$) trivially has the property "$\mu(E) = -\mu(X \smallsetminus E)$", where $X$ is the whole space.

(I suspect, but have never worked through the details, that the only measure on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of a real interval (or product of intervals in $\Bbb{R}^n$) having the complementation property you describe is the zero measure.)